# Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос

```
UPDATE ClientPolicy 
  SET endDate = (
    select min(c.begDate) -  INTERVAL 1 day from ClientPolicy c
    where  
      ClientPolicy.client_id = c.client_id AND c.id > ClientPolicy.id
  ) 
WHERE exists (
  select 1 from ClientPolicy c
  where
    ClientPolicy.client_id = c.client_id AND c.id > ClientPolicy.id ) AND
    (policyType_id BETWEEN 1 AND 2) AND
    deleted <> 1;
```

он выдает ошибку:

> Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Делал подзапросы с временным отношением и сэлфджоином, сэлфджоин не работает ( 1 картинка), на второй картинке без сэлфджоина, внешнуюю таблицу не видит ( очевидно). Как можно исправить? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] : [image]

Comment: Вы бы рассказали, какая такая логика заложена в этот запрос... понять по тексту - малореально. А вообще, скорее всего, запрос надо стереть и переписывать с нуля.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE ClientPolicy 
 SET endDate = ( select min(c.begDate) -  INTERVAL 1 day from (SELECT * FROM ClientPolicy) c
  where  ClientPolicy.client_id = c.client_id AND c.id > ClientPolicy.id ) 
  WHERE exists (select 1 from (SELECT * FROM ClientPolicy) c
 where ClientPolicy.client_id = c.client_id AND c.id > ClientPolicy.id )AND (policyType_id BETWEEN 1 AND 2)AND deleted <> 1;
```

---

Решено